# C# Foreach loop in constructor iterating once

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm in process of making custom JSON file editor.
In order to better manage the data I want to create a tree.
Default JToken and JObject are too complicated to me in order to use them to manage data. That's why I want to convert JObject that is created from input file to a tree.

The basic principle of my code is:
You pass the JToken to the constructor of the Container object;
Container object contains List(of a type Container)child_containers;
If the JToken is complex not primitive it goes through all child JTokens in that
JToken and It creates new Container with that child JToken and adds it to a child_containers list. If input JToken is primitive it saves it's value and it stops the recursion.

```
public class Container
{
    protected GraphicalBlock graphicalBlock;
    //Universal usage
    protected bool IsOriginObject;

    //For primitive containers
    protected object PrimitiveContent;

    //For complex containers
    protected Container child_container;
    protected List<Container> child_elements;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor when provided with raw jobject will create a tree that allows easy data managment.
    /// Constructor is only called once, after that the whole tree will be created recusivly
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input_jobject"></param>
    /// <param name="Is_orig_obj"></param>
    public Container(JToken input_jobject, Point loc, Form main_form_ref, bool Is_orig_obj=true)
    {
        IsOriginObject = Is_orig_obj;

        //Check for complex vs primitive
        if(input_jobject.HasValues)
        {
            //Populate children list with next level/tier tokens
            //Every token will execute the same procedure eventualy creating a tree
            //The main container is the origin of the tree, primitive containers are the end of the branches
            int i = 0;
            JObject job = input_jobject as JObject;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in job)
            {
                child_elements.Add(new Container(pair.Value, new Point(loc.X + i, loc.Y+120) ,main_form_ref, false));
                i=+120;
            }

            graphicalBlock = new GraphicalBlock(loc, true, main_form_ref, this);
        }
        else
        {
            //If token is primitive we can extract value from it
            PrimitiveContent = input_jobject.ToObject<object>();
            graphicalBlock = new GraphicalBlock(loc, false, main_form_ref, this);
        }
    }
}
```

The graphicalBlock object is just a fancy wrapper that i use for adding GUI.
I dont think it affects the loop.

The main problem is after first iteration and creation of first child Container the loops breaks somehow. Can somebody explain why that foreach loop breaks after first token? (No the input JToken don't contain only 1 value).

If somebody has any questions about my code please don't hesitate.
My problem is very specific so I couldnt find it on google or using search tool.

Comment: `The loop is breaking for some reason?` what does the debugger say

Comment: Everything compiles perfectly. The problem is that loop only makes one iteration.
JToken has more values than 1. I want the loop to iterate through all of them.

Comment: TheGeneral asked about the debugger, not the compiler. Go to the first line of the foreach, hit F9 which will put a break point. Run the code. When it stops, step through using the F11 key and hover over variables to see what they hold. Collections will allow you to drill-down to see their count. Things like that. One of the most powerful tools you can have in your coding arsenal is the knowledge of using the debugger.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood his comment.
When i use the debugger the loop manages to create the object, child object constructor then goes through the else section (because first object in Jtoken is primitive) and it returns to the loop and then the loop breaks. Even i+=120; isnt executed.

Comment: So when you debugged. What did you find the count to be for job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the line

```
protected List<Container> child_elements;
```

you are declaring a field with the name "child_element", of type `List<Container>`, but you are not yet creating (instantiating) a list. This field will therefore have its default value of `null`.

When you then try and add something to that "list"

```
child_elements.Add(new Container(...
```

you successfully create that child container but then fail because the list to add to doesn't exist. You probably got a NullReferenceException that was somehow hidden (try/catch at the caller?).

The solution: make sure that field really contains a list by declaring it like this:

```
protected List<Container> child_elements = new List<Container>();
```

Comment: I forgot about it... Thanks for help!
Still I dont know why it failed silently.